# Pybrain Text Classification: data and input

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, feature-extraction, pybrain

I have 3 sets of sentences (varying in word counts), but I don't know how to extract features from the text such that the input dimension will remain the same.

For example, I've tried bag-of-words but, since the word-count variation causes input-dimension variation, I eventually get errors.

I would much appreciate it if you could show me an approach to preparing the string data for the neural network.

Thank you!

(Python 2.7 in Windows 7)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## How to format the input

*This is an extraction from [wikipedia.org](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bag-of-words_model)*

#### Here are two simple text documents:

> John likes to watch movies. Mary likes too.
>
> ---
>
> John also likes to watch football games.

#### Based on these two text documents, a dictionary is constructed as:

```
{
    "John": 1,
    "likes": 2,
    "to": 3,
    "watch": 4,
    "movies": 5,
    "also": 6,
    "football": 7,
    "games": 8,
    "Mary": 9,
    "too": 10
}
```

which has 10 distinct words. And using the indexes of the dictionary, each document is represented by a 10-entry vector:

```
[1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0]
```

**Your input will remain the same size, regardless of the length of your document.** 
I hope this will help you.

Comment: how did you get the vector length 10 from the dictionary?

Comment: There are 10 unique terms in the two documents. The vector length is therefore 10, even though there are 15 words in the document collection in total.

Comment: I'm sorry I still don't get it: where do the entries in both vectors come from?

Comment: The documents listed with yellow background, above.