# Text conversion in python

Tags: python, text, machine-learning, pybrain, supervised-learning

I'm constructing a recurrent neural network with PyBrain for text classification problems. After numerous attempts I still can't sort out how to convert a list of strings into an array that can be used as a dataset. What I did:

```
import collections,re
from pybrain.datasets import SupervisedDataSet

#create the supervised dataset variable with 5 inputs and 1 output
windowSize=5
main_ds = SupervisedDataSet(windowSize,1)

with open('ltest5lg_d1.fr','r') as train_1:
        import_data_train=train_1.readlines()

train_data = []

for lines in import_data_train:
    s = lines.split()        
    for words in s:
        train_data.append(words)

bagsofwords = [collections.Counter(re.findall(r'\w+', txt)) for txt in train_data]

sumbags = sum(bagsofwords, collections.Counter())
```

So I got the frequency table for the training data, but I can't sort out how to convert the data itself to some format that could be used as an input in main_ds variable.

Answer (score 1):

The standard way of representing words in the context of learning is the word embeddings model.

What you want (and this is with only a cursory glance at PyBrain's dataset page [1]) is to build a dataset by converting the text into their vector representations.

For an example of how to do it yourself, see glove-python [2]. If you'd like to use an existing package to do this, see Google's word2vec [3] or Stanford's GloVe [4], of which the python version is a naive implementation.

You could then use this representation to train your NN.

```
[1] http://pybrain.org/docs/quickstart/dataset.html
[2] https://github.com/maciejkula/glove-python
[3] https://code.google.com/p/word2vec/
[4] http://www-nlp.stanford.edu/projects/glove/
```

Comment: Thanks, so I can't do it in Python alone, by constructing dictionaries and bag-of-words?

Comment: Question would be  - what are you trying to do?

Comment: Also, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18070368/pybrain-text-classification-data-and-input?rq=1

Comment: Input in RNN for language modeling. I looked up this question already, still not getting what the values in these arrays stand for. Sorry.

Comment: Alex - what kind of background do you have in math and machine learning? Based on that, I can advise further.